# Jquery: selecting elements that do not only have children with the same class name?

Tags: jquery

How do I make a jQuery selector that selects all elements with the class name "foo", except for those that ONLY have children with the class name of "bar".

```
<!-- Don't select this -->
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<!-- Don't select this -->
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"><p>Some text</p></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"><p>Some text</p></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>


<!-- Select this -->
<div class="foo">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<!-- Select this -->
<div class="foo">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('.foo > :not(.bar)').closest('.foo');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E8UzV/)

Start from all `.foo`, find immediate children except those that have the `bar` class, and revert back to the `.foo`.

Comment: Clever use of CSS selectors ! :-)